# Properly formating and partitioning a USB drive in Lubuntu for Live use

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, lubuntu, format

It might look like an easy thing to do, but I'm experiencing problems in formatting a USB drive so it can be used in Live format. I've used 8 and 16GB USB drives, with the same result. Here's what I do:

1. unmount the drive: `sudo umount /dev/sdb`
2. format the drive: `sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb`
3. partitioning the drive: `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`, followed by this sequence of commands: `n p 1 [intro] +7G a w`

The process seems to work fine, and it exists with the message:

```
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

(Also tried `+4G`, and changing to FAT16 and FAT32, same result.)

`lsblk` now shows this information:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 226,6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  11,9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  14,5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1     7G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I take the drive out and plug it again, but nothing happens. The drive is not automatically mounted, as expected, and it does not show up when I run unetbootin (typically there I can see the `sdb` or the `sdb1` drives that come already installed in a new USB drive).

So, at this point I don't know how to proceed. When I create the Live version in a drive that has not been partitioned (writing to `sdb`) and try to boot with it, it will say that the drive is not a bootable one.

Have made an extensive search in this and other forums (including [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)), but can't find the right information.

Comment: Just use gparted, and create a ms-dos partition table. Then format it as FAT32.

Comment: @GTRONICK After using gparted as suggested, now it mounts correctly, but what was wrong in the procedure above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure was (in part):

2. format the drive: `sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb`
3. partitioning the drive: `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

There are two things wrong with this:

- **Order reversal** -- You need to partition the disk *before* you create a filesystem on ("format") it. This is because partitions hold filesystems, so partitions must exist before filesystems are created. You ended up with a partition that pointed to some semi-random part of the disk rather than to the start of a filesystem.
- **Whole-disk filesystems** -- As just noted, partitions hold filesystems; however, you created a filesystem on the whole-disk device (`/dev/sdb`), rather than on a partition on the device (such as `/dev/sdb1`). This said, though, putting a filesystem on a whole-disk device is legal; it's just *customary* to put filesystems in partitions, and doing so increases flexibility. It's conceivable that it would have worked if you'd omitted step #3; but it's also possible that some of the tools or setup you want to create would *assume* that the disk is partitioned, in which case omitting step #3 would have led to problems later on.

When you used GParted, as GTRONICK suggested, you bypassed both of these problems, because GParted performs the partitioning and filesystem-creation tasks in the correct order, and puts filesystems on the partitions it creates. (The GParted user interface hides the fact that there are two operations, but they are two distinct operations, behind the scenes.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `gparted`, and create a ms-dos partition table. Then format it as FAT32.

The problem could be caused by a non valid partition table, nonexistent or corrupted.